# Python - Warning: Unexpected Error: <class 'IndexError'>

Tags: python, error-handling, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use some code to read username and password from a file called ".logon" and establish a connection to redshift. But I got the error message "Python - Warning: Unexpected Error: ".

Here is my code:

```
def redshift_connect():  
    try:  
        l_user = getpass.getuser()  
        home = expanduser("~")  
        f = open(home + '/.logon')  
        logline = f.readline()  
        usr = logline.split(',')[0].split('/')[1].strip()  
        pwd = logline.split(',')[1].rstrip()  


        conn=psycopg2.connect(host='host-name',  
        port= 5439, user= usr, password= pwd)  
        return conn  
    except IOError as e:  
        print ('I/O error ({0}): {1}: .tdlogon missing!!'.format(e.errno, e.strerror))
    except:  
        print ('Warning: Unexpected Error:',sys.exc_info()[0])  
    else:
        raise ConnectionError('Cannot establish connectionw with Redshift.')
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that this is [horrible python code](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Exceptions): `[...] Never use catch-all except`

Comment: Protip: don't catch the exception unless you output a *useful* error message. This would be much more informative if you *didn't* catch the exception and let it output its full stack trace.

Comment: And the problem is likely that one of those `split(..)` doesn't result in *two* elements, hence `[1]` raises an IndexError.

Comment: So I deleted everything after "except:" and I still get the same error .

Comment: Also: the `else` in a `try` means *if no exception occurred*. So here if nothing went wrong, you're raising an exception just in case?

Comment: Yeah.  There's a reason why the exception info is hidden in a weird construct called `sys.exc_info` and has a complex structure one cannot easily remember:  You are not supposed to use that often.  Just don't catch it if you don't know how to handle it.  Handling can be reraising (just do `raise` in the `except` clause).

Comment: @thatMeow without the bare except clause, you indeed to get "the same error", but this time you should have the full traceback too, so you can find out which statement raised the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the expression `logline.split(',')` works and returns an array with only one entry.  The expression `logline.split(',')[1]` then raises an `IndexError` which you catch in the unspecific `except` clause.